# go outside smoking

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Can I say "go outside smoking", because there is non-smoking area.

1. go for a smoking
2. go smoking
3. go to smoking
   I also want to know if the above sentences are all correct?

Comment: Go smoke outside.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could say "go outside to smoke" or "go outside for a smoke."

1 is incorrect. It should be "go for a smoke" as in "I'll go for a smoke."

2 is fine. For example, "I will go smoke."

For 3, "go to smoke" as in "I am going to go to smoke" would also work.

I'm sorry if I misunderstood your question. If you wanted to make them imperative sentences, then as Jim said, "Go smoke outside" would work.

Answer (score -1):

Say ***go outside for smoking***. You can clearly state the purpose of going outside, and here ***smoking*** is a specific ***act***.

Otherwise, use one of the following:

***go for smoke***, 
***go for a smoke***, or
***go to smoke***

Your listeners can consider ***smoke*** either a mass noun or a countable noun in the first two, and a verb in the last.

Unless it's generally accepted as a kind of ***activity*** (rather than a specific ***act***), which I doubt, ***smoking*** is not used in the same way as we say ***go shopping*** and ***go skiing***. So, when you say  *go smoking* it may sound like *go as you smoke*, just like *go singing* may do. Say ***go for smoking***, or ***go to smoke***, instead.

You don't say *go to smoking* because ***smoking*** is not a place to go to. Likewise, you don't say *go to shopping*, but say ***go to a shopping mall***, or ***go to shop***, in which ***shop*** is a verb.

Comment: 'She went dancing' is a **phase-structure**, [verb + _ing_-form] in the _go shopping_ ( / _gone fishin'_) class. It is unitary. 'She went, dancing' tacks on 'dancing' as an adjunct, a free modifier, and may be paraphrased 'She danced out of the room' (if appropriate) or 'She went. She was [actually] dancing[!]' etc.